# Cannot get my Files to compile in hardhat. getting loop of a few error messages indicating I am either passing too many arguments or not enough

Tags: solidity, erc-20, hardhat, erc-721, erc-1155

I have tried several solutions offered by a few others and have used open AI to try to get some help, but cannot get files to compile.  Please know that I have also tried passing the parameters in the constructor function and get a similar error message.

Here is the error message I receive:

1 failing

1. BCCasino tests
   "before each" hook for "..should deploy correctly":
   Error: too many arguments:  in Contract constructor (count=1, expectedCount=0, code=UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
   at Logger.makeError (node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
   at Logger.throwError (node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
   at Logger.checkArgumentCount (node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:347:18)
   at ContractFactory.getDeployTransaction (node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1216:16)
   at ContractFactory. (node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1244:53)
   at step (node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
   at Object.next (node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
   at fulfilled (node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

/////////////////////////////////

BCCasino.sol

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "./AccessControl.sol";
import "./BCToken.sol";
import "./BCNFT.sol";
import "./BC1155.sol";

contract BCCasino is AccessControl {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;

```
BCCasino public casino;
BC1155 public token1155;
BCNFT public token721;
BCToken public token20;

Counters.Counter public machineIdCounter;

mapping(uint256 => uint256) public machineToAmount;
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public deposits;  //user --> machine -->  amount

event Deposit(
    address indexed user,
    uint256 indexed machine,
    uint256 amount
);

event Reward(
    address indexed user,
    uint256 indexed rewardType,
    uint256 amount
);

constructor() {}

function initialize(address _token20, address _token721, address _token1155) external onlyAdmin {
    token20 = BCToken(_token20);
    token721 = BCNFT(_token721);
    token1155 = BC1155(_token1155);
}


function addMachine(uint256 amount) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
    require(amount > 0, "Invalid amount");
    uint256 machineId = machineIdCounter.current();
    machineToAmount[machineId] = amount;
    machineIdCounter.increment();
    return true;
}

function deposit(uint256 machineId) external returns(bool) {
    require(machineId <= machineIdCounter.current(), "Invalid Machine ID");
    address user = msg.sender;
    uint256 amount = machineToAmount[machineId];
    token20.transferFrom(user, address(this), amount);
    deposits[user][machineId] += amount;
    emit Deposit(user, machineId, amount);
    return true;
}

function reward(address user, 
                uint256 amount, 
                uint256 rewardType, 
                uint256 machineId
) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
    require(rewardType < 3, "Invalid reward Type");
    require(
        deposits[user][machineId] >= machineToAmount[machineId],
        "User didn't make a deposit for the game. Invalid request"
    );

    deposits[user][machineId] -= machineToAmount[machineId];

    if(rewardType == 2) {
        token721.mint(user);
        emit Reward(user, 2, 1);
     } else if (rewardType == 1){
        token1155.mint(user, 1);
        emit Reward(user, 1, 1);
     } else {
        token20.mint(user, amount);
        emit Reward(user, 0, amount);
     }

     return true;
    }

function totalMachine() external view returns(uint256) {
    return machineIdCounter.current();
}
}
```

/////////////////////////////

BCCasino.test.js

// BCCasino.test.js

const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("BCCasino tests", () => {
let token20, token721, token1155, casino;

beforeEach(async () => {
const Token20 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCToken");
token20 = await Token20.deploy((await ethers.getSigner()).address);  // Pass the deployer's address
await token20.deployed();

```
const Token721 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCNFT");
token721 = await Token721.deploy((await ethers.getSigner()).address);  // Pass the deployer's address
await token721.deployed();

const Token1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BC1155");
token1155 = await Token1155.deploy((await ethers.getSigner()).address);  // Pass the deployer's address
await token1155.deployed();

const BCCasino = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasino");
casino = await BCCasino.deploy();
await casino.deployed();

await casino.initialize(token20.address, token721.address, token1155.address); //set toke addresses using initialize function
```

});

it("..should deploy correctly", async () => {
[owner, _] = await ethers.getSigners();

```
expect(await casino.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
expect(await casino.token20()).to.equal(token20.address);
expect(await casino.token721()).to.equal(token721.address);
expect(await casino.token1155()).to.equal(token1155.address);

console.log(owner.address);
console.log(token20.address);
console.log(token721.address);
console.log(token1155.address);
```

});
});